# SQLAlchemy association proxy and lists

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to work out how to get an association proxy on a many to many relationship to return an empty list by default.

So based on the example at:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/master/examples/generic_associations/discriminator_on_association.py

We have:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import as_declarative, declared_attr
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Integer, Column, \
                    String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

@as_declarative()
class Base(object):
    """Base class which provides automated table name
    and surrogate primary key column.

    """
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class AddressAssociation(Base):
    """Associates a collection of Address objects
    with a particular parent.

    """
    __tablename__ = "address_association"

    discriminator = Column(String)
    """Refers to the type of parent."""

    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_on": discriminator}

class Address(Base):
    """The Address class.

    This represents all address records in a
    single table.

    """
    association_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("address_association.id"))
    street = Column(String)
    city = Column(String)
    zip = Column(String)
    association = relationship("AddressAssociation", backref="addresses")

    parent = association_proxy("association", "parent")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(street=%r, city=%r, zip=%r)" % \
            (self.__class__.__name__, self.street,
            self.city, self.zip)

class HasAddresses(object):
    """HasAddresses mixin, creates a relationship to
    the address_association table for each parent.

    """
    @declared_attr
    def address_association_id(cls):
        return Column(Integer, ForeignKey("address_association.id"))

    @declared_attr
    def address_association(cls):
        name = cls.__name__
        discriminator = name.lower()

        assoc_cls = type(
                        "%sAddressAssociation" % name,
                        (AddressAssociation, ),
                        dict(
                            __tablename__=None,
                            __mapper_args__={
                                "polymorphic_identity": discriminator
                            }
                        )
                    )

        cls.addresses = association_proxy(
                    "address_association", "addresses",
                    creator=lambda addresses: assoc_cls(addresses=addresses)
                )
        return relationship(assoc_cls,
                    backref=backref("parent", uselist=False))


class Customer(HasAddresses, Base):
    name = Column(String)

class Supplier(HasAddresses, Base):
    company_name = Column(String)

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session = Session(engine)
```

But if I try to look at the address of a Customer, I get `None` rather than `[]` that I'd expect:

```
(Pdb) foo = Customer()
(Pdb) foo.addresses
(Pdb)  
(Pdb) type(foo.addresses)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Which means I can't simply iterate over `foo.addresses` without first checking it is not `None`.

I tried setting `uselist = True` on the association proxy:

```
        return relationship(assoc_cls,
                    uselist=True,
                    backref=backref("parent", uselist=False))
```

Which sort of works, but then the constructor fails:

```
(Pdb) foo.addresses
[]
(Pdb) foo.addresses.append(Address())
*** TypeError: Incompatible collection type: Address is not list-like
(Pdb)
```

I tried messing with the `creator` to make it construct a list, but then cause all manner of side effects, included nested lists:

```
    cls.addresses = association_proxy(
                "address_association", "addresses",
                creator=lambda addresses: assoc_cls(addresses=[addresses,])
```

Any idea the best way to sort this out properly?

-Matt

Comment: Consider `for item in (foo.addresses or [])`.

Comment: yes, I could do, but it would be much nicer if I could get it to work like regular associations do and handle lists gracefully so I don't have to special case my code everywhere.